# Can't use Class.forName() with v4.app.Fragment

Tags: android

I'm trying to run the below code during onResume().

```
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = this.getSharedPreferences("com.example.appname.MainActivity", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
String foregroundFragment = sharedPreferences.getString("foreground_fragment", "");
try {
    Fragment fragment = (Fragment) Class.forName(foregroundFragment);
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        Log.i("EXCEPTION!", e.toString());
    }
```

However, *Class.forName()* appears to be the wrong method since it gives the following error message:

*"Inconvertible types; cannot cast 'java.lang.Class>' to 'android.support.v4.app.Fragment.'*

I'm not aware of another method that allows me to retrieve a String and use it to initialise a Fragment variable. I've searched online, but haven't been able to find anything other than *Class.forName()*. The string I'm retrieving via SharedPreferences does contain the fragment's full name, ie. *"com.example.appname.ForegroundFragment"*.

Is there another method I should be using? Am I going about this all wrong?

Comment: `Class` type and `Fragment` are not in relation .. Thats why `Inconvertible types` .
Also i am just wondering what exactly you trying to do with this code ?

Comment: @ADM I'm using it to store a reference to the visible fragment when the user switches themes. I was using ViewModel, but it's dumping its content when recreating the activity.

Comment: You do not store reference this Way .. Use `findFragmentByTag` or any other helper methods ...

Comment: @ADM Tags don't persist when their fragment is replaced.

Comment: If you call newInstance then it's no more the same object .. it's a new instance not the same . Now it's look like you only want to know which fragment was previously added ...

Comment: I'm using it to record which fragment is foremost in its hierarchy. However, there are multiple hierarchies that all have their own set of child fragments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with **`newInstance()`**

```
Fragment fragment = (Fragment) Class.forName(foregroundFragment).newInstance();
```

Comment: Thanks @IntelliJ Amiya. This works, as long as all exceptions are handled correctly.